# Como ler de forma otimizada uma lista de dependências de ArrayList?

Tags: java, array

Estou com 4 classes, cada classe tem uma `ArrayList`, onde o último elemento depende de outro `ArrayList`: Exemplo Genêro->Artistas->Albuns->Músicas

Para ler as músicas estou fazendo da seguinte forma.

```
for (Genero ge : objeto.getLista()) {
for (ArtistaObj art : ge.getArtistas()) {
     for (AlbunsObj alb : art.getAlbuns()) {
          for (MusicasObj mus : alb.getMusicas()) {
          }
      }
 }
```

Dentro de cada for eu uso os *getters* para pegar todos os itens da lista, estou usando isso para gravar em um banco e acho q está meio porco, porque na tabela `Musicas` estou usando 4 `for`.

Comment: Parece que não tem muito como melhorar. A não ser que você dê mais detalhes do que está fazendo parece que esta forma está ok.

Comment: Eu só perguntei para saber se tem uma forma otimizada, esta forma funciona mas usar 4 "for" vai contra as boas práticas de programação.

Comment: Onde você viu isso? Precisa rever seus conceitos ou parar de ler coisas escritas por quem não entende do assunto. Se você precisa varrer 4 listas aninhadas e pegar cada uma dos elementos de cada uma delas, não tem como fazer diferente. Dá para escrever de outra forma mas no fundo o resultado será o mesmo. Tem caso que pode até piorar. Pode até existir uma forma me melhorar mas dependeria de circunstâncias que não parece ser o seu caso.

Comment: Talvez se você postar outras partes, explicar melhor, dê p/ pensar em algo melhor. Um detalhes importante é que se você vai gravar em banco, o `for` é o de menos.

Comment: Tu a partir de um genero dado queres saber todas as suas musicas?

Comment: @daniel12345smith Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 3):

Dada a descrição do problema, salvo eu não ter entendido alguma coisa, não há nada melhor que possa ser feito.

Se tiver algum detalhe não explicado, eventualmente pode-se achar um otimização mas não existe milagre. Só se houver um critério que facilite tomar algum atalho.

Uma coisa que pode-se fazer é ter uma única lista que tenha todos os dados, mas dificilmente será uma boa ideia, facilita de um lado, dificulta de outra.

Mesmo com esta solução, você poderá ter um `for`. Mas e daí? Por que isto é um código melhor? Só porque tem menos laços? Isso não significa que o código é mais bem escrito. De qualquer forma provavelmente teria que ter três `if` para identificar a quebra do agrupamento, então talvez seria até pior. E outra, muda a estrutura de dados por causa do algoritmo. Aí sim, seria uma bela de uma má prática na maioria das situações.

E entenda que boa ou má prática se refere aos casos comuns, a um grande número de casos. Elas não podem ser seguidas em todos os casos.

O que você pode fazer é separar isto em métodos para cada interação, assim você só teria um `for` em cada método. Mas ainda teria 4 `for`. Isto deixa o código melhor? Em alguns caos, sim. Mas não necessariamente, depende do objetivo. Separar demais pode trazer tantos problemas quanto amontoar demais. Seria algo assim (a grosso modo):

```
void getGeneros(ArrayList biblioteca) {
    for (Genero genero : biblioteca.getLista()) {
        getArtistas(genero);
    }
}

void getArtistas(ArrayList genero) {
    for (Artista artistas : genero.getLista()) {
        getAlbuns(artistas);
    }
}

void getAlbuns(ArrayList artista) {
    for (Album album : artista.getLista()) {
        getMusicas(album);
    }
}

void getMusicas(ArrayList album) {
    for (Musica musica : album.getLista()) {
        GravaMusica(musica);
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/RecursiveList.java).

É só um exemplo. Tenho dúvidas se é melhor, eu acho que ficou pior, ficou repetitivo dependendo que cada `GetLista()` faz. De qualquer forma acho que os nomes das variáveis e tipos estão melhores definidos aí. Já que você gosta de boas práticas, procure nomear bem tudo em seu programa, isto ajuda bastante. Poderia ser um exemplo melhor mas eu não sei de todo o contexto.

Se o problema for performance talvez seja possível quebrar a operação e colocar os processadores para trabalhar em paralelo, mas aí o problema já seria diferente do que foi descrito. E pode nem valer o esforço.

Answer (score 0):

**Use um estilo Funcional de Programacão**

Dentro da questão que você fez, só existe este idioma e programacão que você coloco e outro voltado para Java 8. Ao final eu cito mais uma opcão, mas que envolve **JPA**

*Para cada* genero, grave o mesmo, e retorne a lista aninhada de Artistas ele para a pŕoxima Funcão.

Ou formalmente: ***Aplique a funcão de salvar para o parametro Genero - o resultado da aplicacão da funcão é a mesma é a Lista de Generos***

**Vamos ao código**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        class MusicasObj {
        }
        class AlbunsObj {
            List<MusicasObj> listMusic = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        class ArtistaObj {
            List<AlbunsObj> listAlbuns = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        class Genero {
            List<ArtistaObj> listArts = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        //Simpleficacão da classe DAO, aqui vc terá o seu método que grava os dados do Genero no Banco, vc precisará de mais DAOs
        class GenDAO{
            Genero save(Genero gen){System.out.println("salvar seu genereo"+gen);return gen;}
        }
        GenDAO dao = new GenDAO();
        List<Genero> listGenero = new ArrayList<>();
        listGenero
            .forEach(g -> dao.save(g)
                    .listArts //Passe a funcão que le os valores do genero e grava ele
                        .forEach(a -> a.listAlbuns
                            .forEach(al -> al.listMusic
                                .forEach(m -> System.out.println(m)))));
    }
}
```

(Por favor note, como estas definicões de classes dentro do método *`main`* são para fins de explicacão)

A principal diferênca é uma reducão de verbosidade, contudo você precisa estar acostumado com a escrita de Lambda Expressions, baseadas no *Lambda Calculus* - https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A1lculo_lambda

A outra opcão é através de um Framework de ORM - Object Relational Mapping, no caso, eu recomendo JPA - você mapeia as suas entidades, para tabelas do banco de dados criando relacionamentos, entre elas através de metadados - annotations - por fim, a implementacão do JPA, como Hibernate fará todo o trabalho de inserir e atualizar as tabelas, e você não precisa criar todo este código.

Exemplo com JPA: 
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToOne

Só mais um detalhe, este código de exemplo não está completo, você precisará alterá-lo e adáptá-lo.